# Execute sql request with select row

Tags: php, mysql, onclick

Hello I would like that when it shows me a line (see image) in my table after the search, interact with the buttons on this line with sql query eg: add the affected or unassigned word in the status column of the line Which appears on the table directly on the php page without past by phpmyadmin
What is possibe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qLJy.png)